# Why is coffee so expensive in Luna: New Moon?

Tags: luna-new-moon

In Luna: New Moon, coffee is described as being ridiculously rare on Luna — I can't understand why that would be the case. Even at modern launch costs it seems like a kilogram of coffee would be no more than $10,000, trivial to a fabulously wealthy Corta. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: $10,000 for a 1kg bag of coffee *is* "ridiculously rare", at least as far as I can tell. Yes, a "fabulously wealthy" person would be able to afford it, but *only* the fabulously wealthy, in much the same way that only they can purchase caviar or truffles or those gourmet meals with grated pieces of gold in them.

Comment: Everything in the book that's not printable or locally growable is described as being insanely expensive, even down to lemon peel and imported fabrics. Presumably cargo from Earth is pricey all on its own and *luxury cargo* doubly so, possibly because it attracts some kind of premium to discourage people from bringing it

Comment: Not knowing the novel, so, a comment. The launch cost you mentioned is just that, the cost. The price for such a delivery can be several times larger than that, depending on the supply and demand. And, after it finally arrives on Luna, the price may be increased several times again, given that it is already there and is available for sale.